# Load file implicitly from Path

Tags: julia

I am trying to get my head around programming with multiple modules (in different files). I don't want to load explicitly the files with `ìnclude` in the right order.

I am using the Atom IDE as my development platform, so I don't run julia explicitly.

when I am just using `importall Datastructures` (where ModuleName is the name of the module) julia complains:

```
LoadError: ArgumentError: Module Datastructures not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("Datastructures")` to install the Datastructures package.
while loading F:\dev\ai\Interpreter.jl, in expression starting on line 8
```

Comment: The file needs to be called ModuleName.jl and only contain the module ModuleName. It needs to either be in your package directory or your `pwd()`.

Comment: Provided I understand it correctly. You give no infomation about the relationship is between ModuleName and DataStructures and Interpreter.jl, and don't describe what you mean by "Path" (if that's the system Path what is your system? Also note that julia uses the environment variable LOAD_PATH, not the system Path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to build a package or module in julia:

**1)** Use the tools in `PkgDev`. You can get them with `Pkg.add("PkgDev") ; using PkgDev`. Now you can use `PkgDev.generate("MyPackageName", "MIT")` (or whatever license you prefer) to build your package folder. By default, julia will build this folder in the same directory as all your other external packages. On Linux, this would `~/.julia/v0.6/` (or whatever version you are running). Also by default, this folder will be on the julia path, so you can just type `using MyPackageName` at the REPL to load it.

Note that julia essentially loads the package by looking for the file `~/.julia/v0.6/MyPackageName/src/MyPackageName.jl` and then running it. If your module consists of multiple files, you should have all of them in the `~/.julia/v0.6/MyPackageName/src/` directory, and then have a line of code in the `MyPackageName.jl` file that says `include("MyOtherFileOfCode.jl")`.

**2)** If you don't want to keep your package in `~/.julia/v0.6/` for some reason, or you don't want to build your package using `PkgDev.generate()`, you can of course just set the files up yourself.

Let's assume you want `MyPackageName` to be stored in the `~/MyCode` directory. First, create the directory `~/MyCode/MyPackageName/`. Within this directory, I strongly recommend using the same structure that julia and github use, i.e. store all your code in a directory called `~/MyCode/MyPackageName/src/`.

At a minimum, you will need a file in this directory called `~/MyCode/MyPackageName/src/MyPackageName.jl` (just like in the method above). This file should begin with `module MyPackageName` and finish with `end`. Then, put whatever you want in-between (including `include` calls to other files in the `src` directory if you wish).

The final step is to make sure that julia can find `MyPackageName`. To do this, you will need `~/MyCode` to be on the julia path. To do this, use: `push!(LOAD_PATH, "~/MyCode")` or `push!(LOAD_PATH, "~/MyCode/MyPackageName")`.

Maybe you don't want to have to run this command every time you want to access `MyPackageName`. No problem, you just need to add this line to your `.juliarc.jl` file, which is automatically run every time you start julia. On Linux, your `.juliarc.jl` file should be in your home directory, i.e. `~/.juliarc.jl`. If it isn't there, you can just create it and put whatever code you want in there. If you're on a different OS, you'll have to google where to put your `.juliarc.jl`.

This answer turned out longer than I planned...

Comment: But why would the OP need to build a whole new package? That doesn't look like what's being asked.

Comment: I think the OP typed `Datastructures` rather than `DataStructures` into Julia, then in the original question typed `ìmportall` rather than `importall`... then the first comment was applied to the second error rather than the first... :)

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Hmmm... now you've made me doubt my interpretation :-)  I decided the question makes perfect sense if you replace the `importall` with a `using` and so just ran with that. It seemed like a good idea at the time (but  maybe that's because I struggled with this stuff when I first started out...)

Comment: thx for this answer, I didn't know about Packages. I am currently using modules as namespaces and just including the files with include.

Comment: @Quonux Do you understand the difference between `importall` and `using`? If not, let me know, and I'll edit my answer to include it. It's fairly important. I suspect it might be the piece that is missing from the puzzle...

Comment: @ColinTBowers yes I do. using imports all and makes them available for method extension